# scripting arrays

Tags: python

Given two input files `File1(person, project, value/time), file2(project, multFactor/efficiency)`, produce `OutputFile(person, total)` - apply multiFactor to the value then sum across to get totals by person.

Comment: This question doesn't even make sense. Did you just copy this over from a homework problem list?

Comment: For instance, WTH does `File1(person, project, value/time)` even mean? What's a multiFactor?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the input into a suitable datastructure (probably a dictionary indexed by the project), do the calculations, output the result.

Comment: -1: This could be an answer to pretty much every question on SO, it's that vague.

Comment: Yes, it's almost as vague as the question!